# Python: How to append ascending integers to elements in a list

Tags: python, append

if the original list `d` is

```
d = [r,f,v,d]
```

how do I make a function to append ascending integers to the strings in the list...

```
d=[1r,2f,3v,4d]
```

Comment: Start with a function... Then show us where you went wrong

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those items in the list are supposed to be strings, try:

```
d = ['r','f','v','d']
for i, item in enumerate(d):
    d[i] = str(i + 1) + item
```

Result:

```
['1r', '2f', '3v', '4d']
```

Comment: you can use `enumerate(d, 1)` and eliminate that +1

Comment: You’re also using `i` for `d[i]`, so I don’t think `enumerate(d, 1)` works.

Comment: @Ry- ah yes there _was_ a reason why I did + 1

Comment: @Ry- good eye didn't see how he was applying it, hes actually modifying the original list so your right it must remain this way

Answer (score 1):

More simply, you can use list comprehension as well.

```
>>> [str(idx)+item for idx, item in enumerate(d)]
['0r', '1f', '2v', '3d']
```

If you want to start the index with 1, use `start`

```
>>> [str(idx)+item for idx, item in enumerate(d, start=1)]
['1r', '2f', '3v', '4d']
```

Comment: purely preference but you can leave out `start` and just use 1, if you knew then sorry for my snob

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Right. Just wanted to make sure that python newbies knows what they use exactly. Thanks tho :)

Comment: ha im a newb too thats why i was sharing we gotta stick together:)

Answer (score 0):

Passing your list to this function should do what you want:

```
    def append_ascending_integers(i_list):
        return [str(idx) + val for idx, val in enumerate(i_list, start=1)]
```

Result:

```
    result = append_ascending_integers(["r", "f", "v", "d"])
    print(result)
```

Comment: You might want to deal with converting the numbers to strings to avoid an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
print([''.join(map(str,i)) for i in zip(range(1,5),d)])
# ['1r', '2f', '3v', '4d']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Nic3500 I pointed out in the main comments for OP lack of effort this was a protest, solution with no explanation